# Matching multiple lines using single regexp

Tags: regex, tcl, file-handling

I have a file which contains

person: male

Pet : dog, cat,

person: female

pet : dog, pig

Like this many persons data is there
I want to get data of only male persons. and their pet.
Like

person: male

Pet : dog, cat,

I am trying to match two line. Thats not working

```
    while{[gets $fh line] > 0} {
     if {[regexp {(person: male.*)\n(pets :.*)} $line match submatch]} {
    puts $match 
    puts $submatch
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are only reading one line at a time. If you read the whole file in (with `read`) then you can do multiline matching.

If you are doing multiline matching, you might find the `-line` option to `regexp` useful, as it means it will only ever match a newline if you explicitly put one in the pattern.

Comment: `set fh [read $file1]
if {[regexp -line -all {^.*(Person: male.*\n.*pets : .*)\n.*$} $fh match]} {
 puts $match
}`

I tried this its only matching the first appearing pattern not all similar patterns.